# Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, google-analytics

running `ionic build android`

and getting the following error:

```
ionic build android
 ✗ (node:7124) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Benda\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-analytics/maven-metadata.xml
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-analytics/
         file:/C:/Users/Benda/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-analytics/maven-metadata.xml
         file:/C:/Users/Benda/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-analytics/
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified

BUILD FAILED
```

cordova plugins:

```
cordova plugins
com.danielcwilson.plugins.googleanalytics 0.6.1 "Google Universal Analytics Plugin"
cordova-plugin-datepicker 0.9.2 "DatePicker"
cordova-plugin-google-analytics 0.8.1 "Google Universal Analytics Plugin"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.5.1-dev "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.2.2-dev "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.2-dev "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.1.3 "SocialSharing"
de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification 0.8.1 "LocalNotification"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.0.1 "Keyboard"
org.apache.cordova.camera 0.3.6 "Camera"
org.apache.cordova.device 0.3.0 "Device"
org.apache.cordova.network-information 0.2.15 "Network Information"
parse-push-plugin 1.0.6 "ParsePushPlugin"
```

ionic info:

```
ionic info

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:
Ionic Version: 1.1.0
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.14
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.0
OS:
Node Version: v6.9.1
```

All necessary SDK and android tools are installed

Please help me understand what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to remove any Google plugin, then update your Android SDK (and Google Play Services inside the SDK) then re-add your Google plugins.